# Conexion ODBC en paquete ssis linux

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, linux, odbc, ssis

alguien ha logrado exitosamente conectar una transaccion dentro de un paquete Ssis en linux para extraer informacion de un servidor Mysql 8, he tratado durante dias de hacer una conexion de este tipo y siempre obtengo el mensaje: **There was an error creating an Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) environment.**

el procedimiento que he seguido es el siguiente:

```
sudo apt-get install libodbc1 odbcinst unixodbc unixodbc-dev

http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/mysql/Downloads/MySQL-8.0/mysql-community-client-plugins_8.0.23-1ubuntu16.04_amd64.deb

sudo wget http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/mysql/Downloads/Connector-ODBC/8.0/mysql-connector-odbc_8.0.23-1ubuntu16.04_amd64.deb

sudo wget http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/mysql/Downloads/Connector-ODBC/8.0/mysql-connector-odbc-setup_8.0.23-1ubuntu16.04_amd64.deb

sudo apt install ./mysql-community-client-plugins_8.0.23-1ubuntu16.04_amd64.deb

sudo apt install ./mysql-connector-odbc_8.0.23-1ubuntu16.04_amd64.deb

sudo apt install ./mysql-connector-odbc-setup_8.0.23-1ubuntu16.04_amd64.deb

sudo nano /etc/odbc.ini
```

```
[PRUEBA]
Driver=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc8w.so
Trace = Yes
TraceFile = /tmp/trace.log
Description      = MySQL connection to  database
Database         = <database>
Server           = <ip db>
User             = <db user>
Password         = <db pass>
Port             = 3306
```

```
echo "select * from usuarios" | isql -v PRUEBA
```

hasta este punto todo va correctamente y obtengo los datos desde el odbc

```
wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -

sudo add-apt-repository "$(wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server-2019.list)"

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y mssql-server-is

sudo /opt/ssis/bin/ssis-conf setup

export PATH=/opt/ssis/bin:$PATH

sudo gpasswd -a <usuario linux> ssis
```

en este punto todo lo necesario para correr el paquete dtsx estan instalados correctamente.

```
sudo /opt/ssis/bin/dtexec /F ./dts/ejemplo.dtsx /de <clave dtsx>
```

al momento de ejecutarlo obtengo la siguiente respuesta.

```
 Error: 2021-04-16 14:11:23.65
       Code: 0xC0014020
       Source: Package Connection manager "mysql"
       Description: An ODBC error -2 has occurred.
    End Error
    Error: 2021-04-16 14:11:23.66
       Code: 0xC0014007
       Source: Package Connection manager "mysql"
       Description: There was an error creating an Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) environment.
    End Error
    Error: 2021-04-16 14:11:23.71
       Code: 0xC00291EC
       Source: Tarea Ejecutar SQL Execute SQL Task
       Description: Failed to acquire connection "mysql". Connection may not be configured correctly or you may not have the right permissions on this connection.
    End Error
    Warning: 2021-04-16 14:11:23.72
       Code: 0x80019002
       Source: Package
       Description: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (1) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
    End Warning
    DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).
    Started:  2:11:16 PM
    Finished: 2:11:23 PM
    Elapsed:  7.188 seconds
```

alguien que haya logrado exitosamente a hacer este tipo de conexion podria señalar que estoy omitiendo o que estoy olvidando. He seguido al pie de la letra los link de microsoft y otros videos aun sin lograr que funcione.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-ssis?view=sql-server-ver15
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-integration-services/odbc-is-supported-in-ssis-on-linux-sql-server-2017-ctp-2-1/ba-p/388346
https://antares.solutions/sql-server-linux/

Agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: ¿Qué pasa cuando haces `ssis-conf setup`? Qué datos usas? El driver es 32bit o 64bit (es sabido que esto causa líos)?